# Proving that if a is satisfiable then b is a tautology by contradiction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification

**I am working on a problem and have been given the following information:**

$a$ and $b$ are two propositional formulas and $\Sigma$={$o_1$,$o_2$,...$o_n$} which is a set of propositional formulas.

If $a$ and $b$ are two propositional formulas without common propositional variables such that $a \models b$ . If $a$ is satisfiable, then $b$ is a tautology.

**My attempt to make a proof for this statement:**

In order to demonstrate that the above statement is true, we can prove that $b$ is a tautology by contradiction. We are going to assume that b is not a tautology.

So, we know by looking at the problem statement that $a$ is satisfiable and that we need to find a valuation $o(b) = 1$ that also complies with $o(a) = 1$. This presents a contradiction because $a$ and $b$ don't have any common propositional variables, so $o(b)=1$ would not be possible unless $b$ were a tautology, because any truthful valuation of $a$ would have no effect in yielding a truthful value in $b$ unless all valuations in $b$ yielded truth (tautology).

Does the above thought process make sense? I am pretty new at proofs and feel like I am going in circles when trying to make a mathematical demonstration. Any feedback / pointing towards the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: *satisfiable* and not "satsfactible", I think... :-)

Comment: Yes, by contra. Assume not, i.e. there is a valuation $o$ such that $o(b)= \text F$. Due to the fact that $a$ and $b$ have no common prop variables, we can freely "merge" that valuation $o$ with a valuation $o'$ such that $o'(a)= \text T$ (there is at least one),  contradicting the entailment relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This presents a contradiction because $a$ and $b$ don't have any common propositional variables, so $o(b)=1$ would not be possible unless $b$ were a tautology, because any truthful valuation of a would have no effect in yielding a truthful value in $b$ unless all valuations in $b$ yielded truth (tautology).

I think you might have the right idea, but your presentation here is definitely a bit confused. I'll try to articulate your approach in a clearer way, so that you can compare these presentations.

So we assume that $b$ isn't a tautology. Let's first introduce notation for the propositional variables in $a$ and $b$. Let's call $(P_1, P_2, \dots, P_k)$ the variables in $a$ and $(Q_1, Q_2, \dots, Q_l)$ the variables in $b$. We're given that these two sets are disjoint.

You should make clear where you use the assumption you're contradicting. It should ideally be in a single step (this helps avoid confusion on both your and the reader's part, but this isn't always possible). So, if $b$ is not a tautology, there exists a valuation $o_1$ such that $o_1(b) = 0$. Since $a$ is satisfiable, there exists a valuation $o_2$ such that $o_2(a) = 1$. Now define a new valuation $o$ by setting $o(P_i) = o_2(P_i)$ and $o(Q_i) = o_1(Q_i)$ for all $i$, which we can do because $P_i \neq Q_j$ for all $i, j$ (we can define $o$ on all the other existing propositional variables randomly). So $o(a) = 1$ and $o(b) = 0$, contradicting the fact that $a \models b$.

I think you're basically articulating the same point, but, as you can see, it's much easier to present if we introduce some mathematical notation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Makes sense! Marked as accepted.